# What objects travel with a creature affected by Banishment?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The banishment spell allows me to send a creature to another harmless plane of existence, where it is incapacitated.

Assuming that all of the creature's equipment travel with it, what other non-equipped objects would travel with it? For example, a creature bound by rope: does the rope go with it or would it be freed when the spell ends?

Comment: Update: DM ruled the rope as part of the PC's equipment and that it would have traveled with him, had I the opportunity to do what I had planned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rules do not attempt to address every possible situation, and this is one that they don't. The DM should make a ruling, and that's how it works.

Comment: Do you know if other spells specify things like this?

Comment: To clarify, it can help answer the question if I can get context from similar spells

Comment: Not that I can think of, no.

Answer (score 1):

> You attempt to send one creature that you can see within range to another plane of existence.

You need to draw the line where it makes sense to you, the extremes are:

- The creature goes naked,
- The creature and everything it is touching goes.

Comment: The creature and everything it's touching isn't quite the other extreme.  I think it's reasonable, for example, to allow the contents of bags and pockets to go, too, if the bag or pocket goes.  That extreme seems to be that the creature and everything *in its possession* goes, potentially including land holdings, bonded persons, etc.

Comment: So if you transit its land holdings one hour after he's banished, do you come upon a gaping hole, or does the land just "close up" like 12 Grimmauld Place, so you step from his east neighbor's land to his west neighbor's in one step?